# How to pass data from a form(input) to another component through service in angular

Tags: angular, service, components

I have 2 components and would like to get inputs of one form and pass these as data to the other component.

component 1:

```js
this.dal = this.form_search.get('dal').value;
this.service.passDataR(this.dal);
```

service:

```js
public S = new Subject<any>();
passData$ = this.S.asObservable();
```

component 2:

```js
this.service.passDataR$
   .subscribe(
     result => {

        console.log('data 1 lista here', result);

      }
   );
```

This should be done through service, since these components dont have any relation.

Problem is that when i call the service form comp1 to comp3 its ok.
But when call from comp3 to comp1 data is udefined. So ima not able to see the result of input from first comp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, the subscriber component(comp3) should be ready by the time you publish from comp1. If you don't subscibe at the moment, the emitted value is lost.

Use BehaviorSubject() instead, which always emits last publised value to its subscribers. In you code simply change -

```
public passSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(**initialValue**);
```

Comment: what value should i pass at initialvalue? I want to pass the value of form from comp1 (this.dalreparto)

Comment: You can pass the default value type of this.dalreparto

if string - ' ' or boolean = true/false. you can to pass undefined or null as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a BehaviourSubject instead? This way, you could set an initial value

```
public passRepartiSource = new BehaviorSubject(/*value*/);
```

Comment: what value should i pass at value? I want to pass the value of form from comp1 (this.dalreparto)

Comment: It really depends on the return type of this.form_search.get('dalreparto').value